# Merge Data Rows c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm using a datatable that is imported by an xml file

So I merge multiple data tables into one data table and get the rows that has the same Agent name and add their values per column in to one data row and put it onto a new table and display it on a data grid view
Example

Input:

```
Agent   Product1   Product2
  A        1          3
  B        4          5
  A        5          4
```

Output:

```
Agent   Product1   Product2
  A        6          7
  B        4          5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope This is what youre looking for :)  Just pass your datatable to **dt** and you will find your required output in **dtFinal**

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Agent");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product2");
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "AA";
        dr[1] = 7;
        dr[2] = 5;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "AA";
        dr[1] = 5;
        dr[2] = 6;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "BB";
        dr[1] = 2;
        dr[2] = 3;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);




 DataView view = new DataView(dt);
        DataTable dtDaysInDocument = view.ToTable(true, "Agent");**//Used to distinct column value**
        string[] dateRecord = dtDaysInDocument.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                            .Select(row => row["Agent"].ToString())
                            .ToArray();



        DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
        dtFinal = dt.Clone();

        foreach (string str in dateRecord)
        {
            DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("Agent='" + str + "'");
            if (rows.Length > 1)
            {
                int finalValue = 0;

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName != "Agent")
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                        {
                            int colValue = row[col] != null ? Convert.ToInt16(row[col]) : 0;
                            finalValue = colValue;
                            DataRow[] dtFinalrows = dtFinal.Select("Agent='" + str + "'");
                            if (dtFinalrows.Length == 1)
                            {
                                string val = dtFinalrows[0][col.ColumnName].ToString();
                                if (val != "")
                                    finalValue = finalValue + Convert.ToInt16(val);
                                dtFinalrows[0][col.ColumnName] = finalValue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DataRow finalDr = dtFinal.NewRow();
                                finalDr[col.ColumnName] = finalValue;
                                finalDr["Agent"] = str;
                                dtFinal.Rows.Add(finalDr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            else if (rows.Length == 1)
            {
                DataRow finalDr = dtFinal.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    finalDr[col.ColumnName] = rows[0][col.ColumnName];
                }
                dtFinal.Rows.Add(finalDr);
            }
```

Comment: @RalphChristianDEclipse :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
group t by t["Agent"]
into newtable
select new {
 Agent = newtable.Key;
 Product1 = newtable.Sum(c=>c["Product1"]);
 Product2 = newtable.Sum(c=>c["Product2"]);
}
```

Comment: How can I make that simpler? because for the future use the user will add a product so how can I make it automatically loop all the columns?
for example I add the product3 column with values like in the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Agent", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Product1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Product2", typeof(int));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", 1, 3});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"B", 4, 5});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", 5, 4});

            DataTable dt2 =  dt1.Clone();

            var sum = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Agent"))
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    key = m.Key,
                    p1 = m.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("Product1")),
                    p2 = m.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("Product2"))
                }).ToList();

            foreach (var row in sum)
            {
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.key, row.p1, row.p2 });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;
```